# How to use `snd_virmidi` on Linux

Tags: midi

I'm trying to wire together a few MIDI apps via virtual MIDI ports, and I found the kernel module `snd_virmidi` that's supposed to manage such ports on Linux.

As a trial, I connect the first virtual MIDI port to the TiMidity output port, then play a MIDI file to the virtual port. I should hear sound, if I understand correctly:

`aconnect 24:0 128:0 # connect VirMIDI 2-0 to TiMidity port 0
aplaymidi file.mid --port 24:0 # play MIDI file to VirMIDI 2-0`

But I am not hearing anything. Playing the same MIDI file to `--port 128:0` does generate sound.

What am I doing wrong, or how can I troubleshoot my setup?

Comment: For what it's worth, the above works when I replace `VirMIDI 2-0` with `Midi Through Port-0` (provided by kernel module `snd-seq-dummy`). Am I misunderstanding the intended function of `snd-virmidi`?

Comment: You might have more luck over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the "Midi Through Port"s is to reflect back any events sent to it.
The purpose of the "VirMIDI" ports is to interface between ALSA sequencer ports (e.g., 24:0) and OSS MIDI devices (e.g., /dev/midi0*).